# discord.js heroku Everything works except embedded commands, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

I was able to follow the tutorial to get my bot online, but it doesn't run any commands. My entire bot works perfectly if I run it locally. I would like to host it to run 24/7 pls!

This is the tail log (idk how to copy paste text from GIT CMD sorry, it should be clear tho)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFHNa.png

I am able to get the bot working for the normal message replies (`bot.on('message', msg => {`), but once I try a prefix command, it kills the bot and can't run anything.

This is the app log I have in heroku logs:

```
2020-05-16T16:03:21.760723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-16T16:03:21.764281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-16T16:03:21.687320+00:00 app[web.1]: I don't want a web process
2020-05-16T16:03:27.931832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-16T16:03:27.853628+00:00 app[web.1]: I don't want a web process
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891630+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891638+00:00 app[worker.1]:       .flat(2)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891639+00:00 app[worker.1]:        ^
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891639+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891640+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891642+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.normalizeFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891643+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageEmbed.addFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:259:42)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891643+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageEmbed.addField (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:250:17)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891644+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/commands/uhelp.js:9:14)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891644+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.bot.on.message (/app/index.js:44:39)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891644+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.emit (events.js:203:15)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891645+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891646+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891647+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.891648+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
2020-05-16T16:03:40.903134+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-16T16:03:40.904074+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-16T16:03:40.906913+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! et@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2020-05-16T16:03:40.907263+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-16T16:03:40.907770+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-05-16T16:03:40.908137+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the et@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-16T16:03:40.908482+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-16T16:03:40.929856+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-05-16T16:03:40.930071+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-16T16:03:40.930236+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-16T16_03_40_922Z-debug.log
2020-05-16T16:03:41.019903+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-16T16:03:41.024710+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-16T16:03:44.579866+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-16T16:03:46.362272+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-05-16T16:03:46.362287+00:00 app[worker.1]: > et@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-16T16:03:46.362288+00:00 app[worker.1]: > node index.js
```

***EDITED LOGS IN***

Edit: so the main problem is, I can't run embedded commands. How do you fix? I just reinstalled the latest node.js version (it didn't do anything).

Thank you so much in advance!!

Second edit - new log: (Node Version v12.16.3 ; Discord.js Version discord.js@12.2.0)

```
2020-05-17T21:52:04.952421+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2020-05-17T21:52:04.978162+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-05-17T21:52:08.718818+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-17T21:52:10.768031+00:00 app[worker.1]: This bot is online!
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574666+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574686+00:00 app[worker.1]:       .flat(2)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574687+00:00 app[worker.1]:        ^
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574687+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574689+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574690+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.normalizeFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574690+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageEmbed.addFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:259:42)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574691+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageEmbed.addField (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:250:17)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574691+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/commands/uhelp.js:9:14)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574691+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.bot.on.message (/app/index.js:44:39)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574692+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.emit (events.js:203:15)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574692+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574693+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574694+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.574694+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
2020-05-17T21:53:07.640438+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-17T21:53:07.643659+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-17T21:53:10.940344+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-17T21:53:12.813527+00:00 app[worker.1]: This bot is online!
```

Comment: Judging by the error, something is trying to hit your bot like it's a webserver and that is crashing it. We're gonna need to see more code before anyone can tell you something useful.

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with the embedding. This is the post I'm referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934727/discord-js-messageembed-fields-flat-is-not-a-function

Comment: I was adding some code and trying to fix it, and when I was pushing, I saw this
```
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   *
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.20.1...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm * (replacing 6.14.4)...
remote:        npm * installed
```
It installs node version 10? Is it supposed to be version 12 or? How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Your bot is failing to start as a webservice, because it's not a web service. [Excerpt from this medium article](https://medium.com/@mason.spr/hosting-a-discord-js-bot-for-free-using-heroku-564c3da2d23f) in part 3.

```
Step 1: Go to the Heroku Dashboard
[....]
Step 3: Under Resources, deselect web and activate the worker
```

Comment: I have deselected the web and activated the worker. I am still unable to use embedded commands. I have edited the new log into the post at the bottom since I can't send it in a comment.