# Missing module for discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, debian, vps

I have a question about the discord boot on Debian9, I'm trying to run my code, but VPS throws me this error. Previously, I had this bot normally on another VPS and everything worked as it should, but now it doesn't work. I don't know if I'm missing any modules or badly installed node and npm.

```
  TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:259:42)
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:368:22)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:259:42)
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:201:14)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
ReferenceError: guildMember is not defined
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:446:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE.js:18:16)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:835:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)
TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:259:42)
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:368:22)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:259:42)
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:368:22)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:450:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:368:22)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
ReferenceError: guildMember is not defined
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:446:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at GuildMemberUpdateAction.handle (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/GuildMemberUpdate.js:30:51)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:825:20)
TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:450:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
    at Client.client.on (/home/bot/main.js:368:22)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
```

I don't know what to do with it, am I missing a module installed?

Comment: A quick search yields this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934727/discord-js-messageembed-fields-flat-is-not-a-function

Comment: In short, your node version is probably outdated and doesn't support `Array.flat()` required by discord.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.flat()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#browser_compatibility) is only available in Node version 11 and later, and discord.js v12 requires Node 12.x or higher. Make sure you're using the latest version. Read more about it on the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start).